# encountered an error - Unexpected token ':'

Tags: git, github-actions, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

```
- name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
  id: task-def
  uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
  with:
    task-definition: ${{ env.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
    container-name: ${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}
    image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}
```

i cant seem to find where is the issue with this workflow step.its on git.

please help & thank you

i have gone through the workflow and the problem is definently within the lines i pasted.

Comment: Can you provide more output about the error? If you can provide the full command that is being run, that would be awesome.

Comment: The above step seems to be fine. Use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to lint your complete workflow and fix those issues. In YAML, the value containing a colon preceding with whitespace also causes syntax errors e.g. `k: v: 123` and to make `v: 123` valid you need to enclose it in quotes i.e. `k: 'v: 123'`. If linting doesn't solve your issue, please include your complete workflow in your question.